# How to manage device on the organizer on window menu on Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have this issue with my Xcode does not recognise my device but my iTunes does. After looking around, some ppl keep saying about [open the Organizer window from the menu Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703290/how-do-you-get-to-the-xcode-provisioning-organizer).

Alright, I can open it. But then ppl said that the window "give you all sorts of information about your devices and provisioning profiles." which in my case, it doesn't. It only list the export history of the app.

On the left column, it only list all the iOS app project, and on the right column it give the option to export. Just that. There's no devices, there's no provisioning profiles, and i certainly do not see any of my device there. Where's the difference ? Am i opening the wrong window ?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: On recent versions of XCode, it's `Windows/Devices`, not `Windows/Organizer` to list your devices.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Window Tab, You will have "Devices" in the list.
Please refer the below picture.[image]

Comment: This is called "Devices and Simulators" in version 10.2.1

Answer (score 1):

Attached devices can be checked under here where it's written iPhone 6. There can be an issue of version support. What version of Xcode you are using and what version on OS in on your device.

[image]